# Installer variable sys.languageId won't be set, when using Replacement script for language code

Tags: install4j

I'm using a replacement script for the language code in install4j to set the language automatically, if the installer is running in the background.
So the replacement script returns the default language code ("en" in my case). 
For some reason the installer variable `sys.languageId` is null, which leads to a NullPointerException.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.setProperty(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.InstallationProperties.setLanguageId(InstallationProperties.java:105)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerContextImpl.finishInstallationProperties(InstallerContextImpl.java:417)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.InstallerContextImpl.finish(InstallerContextImpl.java:339)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.handleCommand(Controller.java:268)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller.start(Controller.java:106)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.runInProcess(Installer.java:58)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Installer.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:85)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:94)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:25)
```

Even, if I try to set the variable explicitly inside the replacement script with  `context.setVariable("sys.languageId", defaultLanguage);`, the variable stays null.
How can I make sure, that variable is set?

Comment: This is a bug in 7.0.5, please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this should be fixed.